# Omniture integration for Roku

Tags: adobe-analytics, roku, brightscript

Can anyone help me to integrate

> Omniture

for Roku Channel?

I couldn't find any document for that

Answer (score 1):

Here is an official repository:
https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/video-heartbeat-v2/tree/master/sdks/roku

You will find library, documentation and samples there.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i am already aware of this but this is associated with adobe marketing, i found the solution already. For omniture we have to use the following .brs file [link](https://app.box.com/s/ps27l0yghzny3nvlq09t) 
Thank you for your precious time